# Sparse matrix using column store on MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

I am new to column store db family and some of the concepts are not yet completely clear to me. I want to use MemSQL to store sparse matrix.

The table would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (
r_id INT,
c_id INT,
cell_data VARCHAR(10),
KEY (`r_id`, `c_id`) USING CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE,
);
```

The Queries:

1. `SELECT c_id, cell_data FROM matrix WHERE r_id=<val>;` i.e. whole row
2. `SELECT r_id, cell_data FROM matrix WHERE c_id=<val>;` i.e. whole column
3. `SELECT cell_data FROM matrix WHERE r_id=<val1> AND c_id=<val2>;` i.e.  one cell
4. `UPDATE matrix SET cell_data=<val> WHERE r_id=<val1> AND c_id=<val2>;`
5. `INSERT INTO matrix VALUES (<v1>, <v2>, <v3>);`

The queries 1 and 2 are about equally frequent and 3, 4 and 5 are also equally frequent. One of Q1,2 are equally frequent as one of Q3,4,5 (i.e. Q1,2:Q3,4,5 ~= 1:1).

I do realize that inserting into column store one row at a time creates Row segment group for each insert and thus degrading performance. I cannot batch the inserts. Also I cannot use in-memory row store (the matrix is too big).

I have three questions:

1. Does the issue with single row inserts concern updates too if only `cell_data` is changed (i.e. Q4)?
2. Would it be possible to have in-memory row table in which I would do INSERT (?and UPDATE?) operations and periodically batch the contents to column table?

   - How would I perform Q1,2 if I need most recent data (?UNION ALL?)?
   - Is it possible avoid executing Q3 for both tables (?which would mean two round trips?)?
3. I am concerned by execution speed of Q1 and Q2. Is the Clustered key optimal for those. I am not sure how the records would be stored with table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Yes, single-row updates also perform poorly - they are essentially a delete and an insert.

2.
Yes, and in fact we automatically do this behind the scenes - the most recently inserted data (if it is too small a number of rows to be a good columnar segment) is kept in an in-memory rowstore form, and read queries are essentially looking at a UNION ALL of that data and the column-oriented data. We then batch up this data to write into column-oriented form.

If that doesn't work well enough, depending on your workload, you may benefit from explicitly keeping some of your data in a rowstore table instead of relying on the above behavior, in which case:

2a. yes, to see the most recent data you would use UNION ALL

2b. the data could be in either table, so you would have to query both (like for Q1,2, using UNION ALL works). This does not do two round trips, just one.

3.
You can either order by r or c first in the columnstore key - r in your current schema. This makes queries for a row efficient, but queries for a column are going to be very inefficient, they may have to scan basically the full table (depending on the patterns in your data). Unfortunately columnstore tables do not support using multiple keys, so there is no good way to solve this. One potential hacky solution is to maintain two copies of your table, one with key (r, c) and one with key (c, r) - this is essentially manually maintaining two indexes.

Based on the workload you're describing, it sounds like you are doing many single-row queries (Q3,4,5, which is 50% of the workload), which rowstore is much better suited for than columnstore (see http://docs.memsql.com/latest/concepts/columnstore/). Unfortunately, if it doesn't fit in memory, there isn't really a good way around this other than perhaps to add more memory.